# Video-js custom skinning

Tags: javascript, css, html, customization

I am using the 'less2css' css editor for customising video-js.
to save a custom skin, it states 'replace all instances of 'vjs-default-skin'with new name..

to be clear, I have to change EVERY instance of that name that i find ANYWHERE within the css file?

there is no shortcut to do this within 'less2css' "

thanks,

keith.

Answer (score 0):

Hi reddog i believe this link will help u rather than editing default css add ur custom class as mentioned in below link.                http://www.videojs.com/docs/skins/